# Timer still running after unloading the form

Tags: vb6, timer

i got a code in vb6:

```
If KeyCode = vbKeyEscape Then
        i = MsgBox("you want to quit?", 4)
        If i = 6 Then
            Timer1.Enabled = False
            Unload Me
        End If
 End If
```

after the form unloaded and 10 seconds interval , the timer event still got executed. 
this code is in another form besides the main form.

Comment: Is the timer in the main form?

Comment: If the timer is on another form, can you show us your full code including the reference to the other form?

Comment: Oh, and it's better to do this in the QueryUnload() event to catcher the user clicking the X, etc.

Comment: #Deanna i got two forms:`main` and `game`. this code is on the game form, what i want to do is to quit the game form and go back to the `main` form. after the code above the `game` form disappeared, but the timer event still got executed

Comment: And don't use magic numbers, there are MsgBox constants for a reason :)

Comment: @dannynjust: Try setting `Enabled = False` for the timer in design time. This way accidentally loading the `game` form will not start the timer. Why `game` form is loading after being unloaded is what you should investigate in your case.

Comment: sorry, i got caught up in something else, so  havn't have time to look into this. sorry for the delay.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the timer is firing after unloading the form, something is causing the form to be reloaded, OR there are two instances of the form loaded.

For the first case, try adding a breakpoint in the `Form_Load` event and single stepping over the unload code to see what's triggering it.

For the second case, make sure you use EITHER the implicit "game" global reference for the form, OR create use an explicit local reference to hold the loaded form. I expect your still using the implicit global reference.

Answer (score 1):

Timers firing after their parent form is unloaded is common problem in VB6.  The WM_TIMER message can be dispatched while your VB6 code is running that Unloads the forms.  This leads to the event getting raised late.  Declare a private boolean `mbIsLoaded` at the form level.  Assign it to `True` in the `Form_Load` and `False` in `Form_Unload`.  In your timer event handler make this your first line of code:  `If mbIsLoaded Then Exit Sub`.

Comment: Excellent suggestion. Also consider [stopping all timers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41446618/vb6-killing-timers) on that form before unloading the form.