# VB6 killing timers

Tags: timer, vb6

I'm programming in VB6 because we are using legacy code and hardware (external electronics).

My programs are build around timers where I would use tasks in OS programming. The timers are running until their job is done. A flag is set and another timer is started.

I want a supervisory timer that controllers the other timers When the timers produce no result or are waiting for a real world event that never comes (Do while loop) I want to kill the timer. In electronics we have a 'watch dog timer' it checks if the code is still running (and producing results). I want to do a watch dog timer in VB6.

Timers in vb6 have Timer.interval and Timer.enabled. I'm unable to kill the timer with these tools. I can prohibit a timer from starting. I know of a few ways to kill a loop. Like counting the laps and breaking out when the maximum is reached. Or even checking checking a flag.

**Is there a way of killing a VB6 timer? If not whats the best way to avoid infinite loops?**

Side question: Is there a way of listing what timers are running?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have answered you own question, setting `.enabled` to false will prevent the next interval from firing.

To "kill" the timer when its interval is *already running* you would need to check for a flag and exit within the running method/s. (There is no other way as all of this is happening on a single thread)

> Is there a way of listing what timers are running?

```
Dim ctrl As VB.Control
For Each ctrl In Me
    If TypeOf ctrl Is VB.Timer Then
        Debug.Print ctrl.Name, "running: "; ctrl.Enabled And ctrl.Interval > 0
    End If
Next
```

Comment: Plus one. Here is a [link to the Microsoft VB6 Timer documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa445561(v=vs.60).aspx) for good measure. It says "Whenever the `Timer` control's `Enabled` property is set to `True` and the `Interval` property is greater than 0, the Timer event waits for the period specified in the `Interval` property."